# Filter elements in DOM based on data-attr with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to filter these items with jQuery autocomplete according to their data-name, but I got stuck with it a bit. Generally, I want to start typing the text in the input field and remove items from DOM if they don't match. Any help is much appreciated.

Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aVGjay

```js
 $(function() {
      var item = $(".item");
    
      $.each(item, function(index, value) {
        console.log($(value).attr("data-name"));
        var everyItem = $(value).attr("data-name");
      });
    
      $("#my-input").autocomplete({
        source: everyItem, //?
        minLength: 1,
        search: function(oEvent, oUi) {
          // get current input value
          var sValue = $(oEvent.target).val();
          // init new search array
          var aSearch = [];
          // for each element in the main array
          $(everyItem).each(function(iIndex, sElement) {
            // if element starts with input value
            if (sElement.substr(0, sValue.length) === sValue) {
              // add element
              aSearch.push(sElement);
            }
          });
          // change search array
          $(this).autocomplete("option", "source", aSearch);
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
  .items {
      width: 200px;
    }
    
    .item {
      background-color: red;
      margin-top: 2px;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Filter items" id="my-input">
   <div class="items">
      <div class="item" data-name="one">one</div>
      <div class="item" data-name="two">two</div>
      <div class="item" data-name="three">three</div>
    <div class="item" data-name="four">four</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is best I came up with, I am just looking for solution to filter elements(which will be added to DOM from the database eventually) by their data-name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little odd to use autocomplete for this, as that's intended to build a filtered option list from a provided object or remote data source, not from DOM content.

You can build the functionality yourself by attaching an input event listener to the `#my-input` which in turn goes through the `.item` elements and uses a regular expression to filter ones with matching `data-name` attributes and displays them, something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var $items = $(".item");

  $('#my-input').on('input', function() { 
    var val = this.value;
    $items.hide().filter(function() {
      return new RegExp('^' + val, 'gi').test($(this).data('name'));
    }).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.items {
  width: 200px;
}

.item {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Filter items" id="my-input">
<div class="items">
  <div class="item" data-name="one">one</div>
  <div class="item" data-name="two">two</div>
  <div class="item" data-name="three">three</div>
  <div class="item" data-name="four">four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome mate, you saved me a lot of time, thank you!

Comment: Sure, `^` is the 'beginning of string' anchor. `gi` are the modifier flags, `g` means this is a global search (which thinking about it, is not relevant to this) and `i` mean case insensitive matching

Comment: Thank you!(sorry, deleted comment accidentally). I'm still amazed by the simplicity of your solution

Comment: is it perhaps possible to modify the expression to search by every letter in the word?

Comment: Sure, remove the `'^' + ` from the regex.

Comment: I owe you a beer